How am I able to add a 15 minute pause to a Runscope test between API calls, beyond using 5 180 second Pauses?
I am trying to make a call to an API, wait 15 minutes, and make another call to that same API. There are API calls before and after these two, but this 15 minute pause is giving me some trouble. The maximum amount of time that a "Pause" in Runscope can be configured for is 180 seconds. It seems as if I can chain 5 180 second Pauses back to back to accomplish a 15 minute total Pause, but I am trying to figure out if there is a cleaner way to make this work or if there are pitfalls to chaining the build-in Pauses in this way.
I have tried adding 5 pauses of 180 seconds back to back to back to back to back, and this seems to work, but is not ideal.
